# Paypal Express Checkout paymentinfo_0_amt value returned

Tags: paypal, vbscript, express

I am testing using the sandbox at the moment new functionality to use paypal express as a payment method. I have successfully made a payment and am inspecting the returned
values from the DoExpressCheckoutPayment

One of the fields returned is PAYMENTINFO_n_AMT and my vbscript code is
PPFamt = resArray("PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT") ' The final amount charged, including any shipping and taxes from your Merchant Profile. 

I would expect this value to match the total amount being requested (from the Set) but
it seems to be rounded. 
i.e. if I request a payment of 217.85 - the PPFamt value is 218.00 
if I request a payment of 66.90 - the PPFamt is 67.00 
I am using GBP currency for both the seller and buyer accounts.

Has anyone else come across this? I can't see that I am doing anything wrong or rounding it in the code, so I am assuming Paypal is doing this. 
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I'm not aware of any scenario where PayPal would round these values.  Can you provide an example transaction ID or EC token so that I can check to see what was sent to PayPal and what PayPal responded with?

Comment: I think the rounding must be happening on your end before sending the final request to PayPal.  Keep in mind that DoExpressCheckoutPayment is the end-all-be-all.  Whatever gets sent in that is what gets used.

Comment: Doh! it was my fault! I had a clng in the code that I didn't spot.  I think I just needed a virtual "kicking" to ensure I saw my own mistake, strange how you can't see your own errors but someone else can see them straight away. Sorry for wasting your time, I shall now go away and beat myself up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error - paypal was just returning the value I sent in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment stage.